# Existence of solutions to y'' = f(x)y

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was reading some results earlier concerning properties of solutions to equations of the form
$$y'' = f \left(x \right) y$$
paired with initial conditions $y (x_0) = y_0$, $y' (x_0) = y_0'$, where $f$ is continuous. I was wondering -- is there an easy proof that solutions exist in general? My work in progress is to allow $z$ to solve the first-order nonlinear nonhomogeneous system 
$$z' + z^2 = -f (x)$$
Then if we set
$$y = e^{\int z dx}$$
we obtain that 
$$y'' = (z' + z^2)y = f (x) y$$
I'm not happy with this solution however -- there are definitely some pieces missing (the integral of $z$ existing being just one of them) and I don't know if this method can be fixed.

I'm aware that there are (complicated) existence and uniqueness results for more general systems, but I want to avoid this. I'm fine with using Picard-Lindelof, however. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's a linear equation with variable coefficients. As long as such coefficients do not blow up the standard existence and uniqueness theorem will give global existence for your initial value problem. (Unless, of course, you wrote $f(x)$ but meant $f(y)$).

Comment: denotes $$y=f(x)$$ here?

Comment: The equation in your title and the equation in your question are different.

Comment: I've fixed the title. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Picard-Lindelof. Let $u = y'$, Then $$u' = f(x) y$$ so the vector $v = \binom u y$ satisfies the first order equation $$v' = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & f(x) \\1&0 \end{pmatrix}v =  A(x)v$$ which locally has a unique solution due to Picard-Lindelof (in fact, if $f$ is bounded, there is a unique global solution).

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you!